# Add upcoming chat events to the various Twitter bots

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, twitter

It would be nice if upcoming chat events were auto-tweeted by the appropriate Stack Exchange Twitter accounts (perhaps 15 minutes prior to the event?).  That is, by the dedicated account for the non-beta sites that have a dedicated account, and the generic Stack Exchange account for the others.

This makes it easy for those following the account to find out about upcoming events, and to retweet them to promote more widely.

Comment: Another good idea; you are on a roll!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the case now; the same events that may be announced via a banner on the parent site will also be tweeted (i.e. the event happens in a fully public room and was created by a user who is a moderator on the room's parent site).

The first test case should be tonight's SciFi [recommendation chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule) tweeted by [@StackSciFi](https://twitter.com/#!/StackSciFi).

Comment: Saw the tweet this morning :) thanks!